# Do I need to release an NSArray returned by sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The documentation for `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` say that it returns a copy of the receiving array.

What does this mean with regards to the returned object's retain count?

Do I need to release it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Copy" here means an array with its contained pointers copied. It's a different array from the one receiving that message, so its retain count is entirely different from the original. It's also autoreleased as the method name doesn't contain any of the words "new", "copy", "retain", "alloc" or "init".

Comment: +1 the general rule is that anything that is not "ALLOC'd" by you will be autoreleased. And anything which is retrieved from a static function/message is autoreleased.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to care whether the array you get from `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` is autoreleased or not.  What matters is whether *you* have copied, retained, or allocated it.  If not, then don't release it.

Comment: +1 Asking "what is the retain count?" or "is it autoreleased?" is the wrong question. What you need to know is: "do *I* need to release it?"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about a leak here. It says copy to tell you that it is not the same array sorted, rather a whole new array object.